# I heard you liked DIVs so I put your DIV in your DIV

Tags: css, html

Apparently my brain has turned to mush this morning. I feel certain the answer is obvious but I can't figure out what I'm doing dumb. I'd guess it's something wrong with the CSS so here's that:

```
.fulldiv {
    border:2px solid green;
    background:white;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 5px;
    width:97.5%;
}
.fulldiv h2 {
    background:green;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    margin:0;
}
.fulldiv p {
    padding: 5px 5px;
    margin:0;
}

.thirds {
    border:2px solid cyan;
    background:white;
    margin: 10px 0;
    width:31.5%;
    float:left;
    margin-left:5px;
}
.thirds h2 {
    padding: 10px 5px;
    background:cyan;
    margin:0;
}
.thirds p {
    margin:0;
    padding: 5px 5px;
}
```

The full shenannigans can be seen at this 
[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aslum/C9MZp/).

Shouldn't the third .hicon div be separate from the the previous one? Why are the three thirds divs chilling inside the final div? What am I overlooking?

Comment: http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/11111/111113173/3214163-yo+dawg.jpg

Comment: I feel I should edit your title, but I also feel this would make me a kill joy.

Comment: You're probably actually right, but I couldn't think of a better, descriptive title that actually explained the problem. /:

Comment: problems been solved now, title can remain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[You need to add](http://jsfiddle.net/C9MZp/3/):

`<div style='clear:both;'></div>`

After the final `.thirds` div in order to clear the floats you have in place and resume the document flow.

Alternatively you can use a css [clearfix](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) on the nth-child(3) of `.thirds` (or add a clearfix class directly)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a case for clear fix! I've added in the [microclearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) by Nicolas Gallagher, but there are plenty out there.

http://jsfiddle.net/C9MZp/4/

```
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}
```